# Eclipse cannot create a Runnable JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am trying to export a runnable jar file using eclipse. But everytime When I go through the steps suggested by eclipse and the community here, it comes up with  following error:

```
   No resources selected
    Jar export finished with problems. See details for additional information.
       Could not find main method from given launch configuration.
```

I even tried exporting a simple hello world jar file, but the same error keeps coming up

Any ideas on how I can fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You run in [Eclipse bug 525711](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525711) which is already fixed. Upgrading to Eclipse Oxygen.2 will fix it: _Help > Check for Updates_.

Comment: See this, https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm] but select the Runnable Jar and the messages  you are getting "Jar export finished with problems" because your class contains warnings., hope it will help you.

Comment: I had the same issue. Removed the Run configurations and have retried the runnable jar creation and able to proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

Here I'll mentioned the step's. Try this on probably you will get Runnable jar.

1. Open **file menu** in eclipse and then select **Export option.**
2. Then select **java option** within that select **Runnable Jar File option** and then press next.
   3.Here within **lunch configuration** select the starting file you want for Runnable jar and then select the **Export destination** by browse option.
3. And then finish, you will fined executed jar created at your select destination.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue while exporting one of the jar application.

Solution:

1. Check the run configuration for the Java application
2. If there are multiple run configurations make sure the name of the run configuration is same as the project